# CSS Sprites don't work

Tags: css, css-sprites, sprite

I need to embed social network sprite on my html page, but for some reason they don't display (whereas the links themselves work). Here is my html:

```
<div class="sprites">
    <a class="instagram" href="http://instagram.com"></a>
    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com"></a>
    <a class="facebook" href="https://fb.com"></a>
    <a class="vk" href="https://vk.com"></a>
    <a class="pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com"></a>
    <a class="youtube" href="https://youtube.com"></a>
</div>
```

and fiddle with scss: http://jsfiddle.net/zvj89o0o/ 
And below is what my sprite looks like:

[image]

Comment: Use the the absolute URL for the when you're referring to the image in fiddle.

Comment: Almost there.. Just update the baackground url with an absolute url for it to work with fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvj89o0o/1/

Comment: [Updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/zvj89o0o/2/) of @karthikr's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvj89o0o/1/)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Thank you - you have too much patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.youtube, .pinterest, .vk, .facebook, .twitter, .instagram {
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
    background: url("path/to/jI86i.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: And do you know how i can use it with SVG?

Comment: I can't imagine it would be any different. As the only difference I think is that it's a scalable image. But did my answer help? :) @DenisYakovenko

Comment: It did) Well, i mean when i change the background image to the same .svg file, it stops displaying

Comment: Hmm try the tutorial at [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/)

Answer (score 1):

It works well, but you have forgot (in the fiddle) to have a background URL that is valid.

I tried with the image you have above in this post, and it works well (will need some adjustments):

http://jsfiddle.net/gau66y74/

[image]

I refer to this CSS:

```
.youtube, .pinterest, .vk, .facebook, .twitter, .instagram {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI86i.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

To fix the HOVER issue, use :

```
.youtube:hover {
        background-position: -256px -384px;
}
```

in stead of:

```
.youtube {
    background-position: -256px -256px;
    &:hover {
        background-position: -256px -384px;
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing that (only for YouTube icon)

Comment: Posted this before reading in a comment above. I see Karthikr has written the same.